# Error External table is not in the expected format

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I am trying to get data to `sqlserver2005` on my `C#` windows application, from sheet1.xls file through oledb connection in visual studio-2008 and I am using windows7 os and I didn't installed excel on my system.

This is my connection string:

```
 string excelconnectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +excelfilepath + ";"+"Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;'";
```

I tried many ways but still i am getting this error :

```
"External table is not in the expected format. "
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` for excel files

```
string excelconnectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +excelfilepath + ";"+"Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes";
```

[connectionstrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/)

Comment: i installed AccessDatabaseEngine.exe(Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable) and i tried again but still iam getting the same error

Comment: can you provide your connection string@FADV

Comment: string excelconnectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelfilepath + ";" + "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;'";   and the excel file path is:C:\sheet1.xls

Comment: i changed the string like u given above,but still having the same problem. i am using .xls format that is old version of excel(97-2003)

Comment: It may be possible that your Excel file itself contains some invalid data. That's why OleDB will not be able to read your Excel sheet.